# Stored procedure modified time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to find out when a stored procedure or table was last modified?  I tried checking the properties via SQL Management Studio, but only found the creation date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this to find the last modified date for a stored procedure:

```
select name, create_date, modify_date
from sys.procedures
where name = 'sp_MyStoredProcedure'
```

You can use this to find the last modified date for a table:

```
select name, create_date, modify_date 
from sys.tables
where name = 'MyTable'
```

To find the last modified date and other info for other objects, you can query `sys.objects` .  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx contains a full list of types you can search for.

```
select top 10 * 
from sys.objects 
where type in ('p', 'u')
```